# DSL plugin wrappers not working

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

DSL script is written in groovy. I am trying to use wrappers for a pipeline job. I can not see same once I run my dsl script. i have seen this issue for some of other dsl api as well, am I using a wrong way or what. Jenkins versions is 2.89.2, DSL, pipeline, workspace, logsizechecker plugin is latest and installed.

```
pipelineJob('dev') {
parameters {
    stringParam('NICK', 'vgn')
    stringParam('ECR_REPO', 'xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com')
    stringParam('ECRHOTFIX_TAG', '')
}
logRotator(-1, 50, -1, -1)
configure {
     it / definition / lightweight(true)
}
triggers {
    cron('0 */6 * * *')
}
concurrentBuild(false)
wrappers {
    preBuildCleanup()
    logSizeChecker {
        maxSize(1024)

    }
}
definition {
    cpsScm {
        scm {
            scriptPath ('Jenkinsfile')
            git {
                branches('*/dev')
                remote {
                    url ('git@github.com:xxxxx/xxxxxx.git')
                    credentials ('jenkins-key')
                }
                extensions{
                    cloneOptions {
                      noTags(true)
                      shallow(true)
                      timeout(30)
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins DSL pipeline syntax for wrappers or publishers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48193600/jenkins-dsl-pipeline-syntax-for-wrappers-or-publishers)

Comment: Yes, Both question is mine. Just looking forward if any of one answered.

Comment: Not sure what this plugin is for. Now upstream publishers not working, Even I can see it is configured, Build is not triggering up.

Answer (score 0):

The Pipeline job type does not support wrappers. It's a problem in Job DSL that the syntax is available and does not cause a runtime error. See [JENKINS-31832](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31832) in the Jenkins bug tracker.